# File not running on startup

Tags: scripts, startup

I have a file that starts another script in a folder. When I run this file using command

```
 sh /etc/init.d/scriptname
```

it runs the other script fine. The file has the `001` permission that I assumed it needed. However it isn't running. Why isn't it and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 2 chmod`. The interpreter has to be able to **Read** the script, as well as knowing the script is executable. Usually, I have my scripts set to `755` or `555`.

Comment: Neither of these worked.

Comment: Is the first line of your script a `#!/bin/sh`? Is the filesystem mounted with the `noexec` option? Does `scriptname` have all the  `/etc/init.d` header stuff? Did you try it with `sh -x /etc/init.d/scriptname`? Where is the "other script in a folder"? Is it mounted when `scriptname` runs?

Comment: Sorry @waltinator but that was was too complex for me to follow.

Comment: Which parts were "too complex"? If you have simply copied a script into `/etc/init.d` without figuring out how `init` does things, you are doomed.